# How to use server databound controls for JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

Can I use the data from a server-side databound DropDownList or ASP.NET Gridview for a JQuery Autocomplete?

I understand these databound controls get rendered to client-side html anyway. Is there a way that the JQuery Autocomplete can use them?

Im thinking of databinding a Gridview, visble=false it, then populate the Jquery Autocomplete with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to find the right selector, i don't really use webforms, but checking out questions here i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261845/webforms-and-jquery-how-to-match-the-ids) question which discusses the problems related with it, one possible solution is to use something like this. Also [this](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/custom-jquery-selector-for-aspnet-webforms/) blog post might help.

```
$('#<%= gridview.ClientID %>').autocomplete({source:[]});
```