# How to scroll to a specific item in a Repeater using anchor or anything else ? (on page load)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to the page to scroll to the item where a condition is met. I have learned how to use this (which worked for client side tags) :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#c66';", true);
```

But I could not scroll to specific Item. I tried to change ID of a hiddenfield inside the itemtemplate on _ItemDataBound() event but still not working.
What should I do ?

I've spend most of my day searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to do this by using JavaScript, because using server-side code to do this will render auto-generated client-side code and may be less understandable.

Here is a question that will help to do it using jQuery, using the id of the tag generated. You may do this using either id, CSS class, data-attribute, etc. [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Besides, if you want to do it using the id, you may need this other info to render the final id that you can see in the browser, since this differs a lot from the one you code in the *.aspx file. [Webforms and jQuery, how to match the ID's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261845/webforms-and-jquery-how-to-match-the-ids)

Comment: I am talking about repeater here, so it has be done in server side. These links are completely useless.

Comment: A repeater is just a control that foreaches a list and render what you are putting inside it. You can still do it using JavaScript and, as far as I am concerned, this is still the best practice. However, you should do the most mantainable solution for your current project. Sorry for not giving the answer you were expecting :)

Comment: Well sorry if my reply seemed rude but i really wasted my whole day on this. I gonna try this again..